# Как посчитать выводимые в key значения?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Есть кусок кода

```
if (substr($key,0,4) == "AIR/" && in_array(substr($key,4,3),array("123","321","567","894","111","222","564","864")))
{
echo "\n* $key *\n";
```

который выводит в конце концов значения в таком виде:

```
* AIR/564-0000906c * * AIR/321-00008cab * * AIR/222-0000806f * * AIR/111-00009067 *
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, как мне считать $key перед выводом. Мне надо получать число сколько там значений, разделителем служит звездочка *, потому что оно выводит все в одну строку, и я не знаю, как такое можно посчитать.
Я думал, может, считать сколько в строке будет AIR/ встречаться, такое число и выйдет, но у меня все равно не выходит. Пробовал считать через count($key), но оно выводит 1, потому что оно, наверно, считает всю строку)

Помогите.

Пробовал так:

```
$n = $n + 1;
```

echo `"\n* $n *\n"`; 
выводит

```
* 1 * * 2 * * 3 * * 4 *
```

Мне нужно получить конечное число 6, ведь если даже сделаю каунт $n, оно мне единицы выведет.

Comment: честно, я ничего не понял)))) можно по другому как нить перефразировать задачу и проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Я понял вашу задачу так:

```
$str = '* AIR/564-0000906c * * AIR/321-00008cab * * AIR/222-0000806f * * AIR/111-00009067 *';
$count = preg_match_all('/AIR\/[\d]{3}-[0-9a-z]{8}/', $str, $matches);
echo $count; // 4
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ.  
Не совсем то, что я ищю...

Код

    if (substr($key,0,4) == "AIR/" &&     in_array(substr($key,4,3),array("123","321","567","894","111","222","564","864")))
    {

// ПРИМЕР если сдесь я сделаю echo $key, оно мне выведет    
* AIR/564-0000906c * * AIR/321-00008cab * * AIR/361-00008cab *  
Делаю по вашему примеру, подставляю $key под матчес  

    $count = preg_match_all('/AIR\/[\d]{3}-[0-9a-z]{8}/', $key, $matches);
    echo $count;

// оно выдает 111 (три цифры 1), мне нужно получить в данном случае 3.
Понимаете что я имею в виду?

Comment: @ya_sf, сдаётся мне, что вы в цикле делаете поиск preg_match_all. Если это так, то суммируйте полученные количества.

    // где-то вначале
    $count = 0;
    // в цикле
    $count += preg_match_all('/AIR\/[\d]{3}-[0-9a-z]{8}/', $key);

Comment: Что-то не помогло*(

Грубо говоря, вот весь участок кода

   if ($air_channels)
{
ksort($air_channels);
foreach ($air_channels as $key => $value)
{
  if (substr($key,0,4) == "SIP/"  && in_array(substr($key,4,3),array("123","321","658","965","547","354","346","348","189","147","123","157","121","325","359","796","724","701")))
  {

// потом делаю что-то

Answer (score 0):

Можете в цикле получать данные и проверять или что то с ними делать с ними.

```
<?php

$str = '* AIR/564-0000906c * * AIR/321-00008cab * * AIR/222-0000806f * * AIR/111-00009067 *';

preg_match_all('/AIR\/([\d]{3})-([0-9a-z]{8})/', $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) // здесь чтото делаете со своими данными
    echo "в ".$matches[0][$i][0]." (первое)->".$matches[1][$i][0]." (второе)->".$matches[2][$i][0]."\n";

?>
```

[вот рабочий пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eaffe993eefdf9d70c737773df089e8844f79a96)